# Get ASCII Results in MySql cli Queries

Tags: mysql, ascii

I am trying to put the following value into a mysql table:

```
  lT~:uc9%7 4M?;~=0=^
```

so i:

```
 update table set field='lT~:uc9%7\04M?;~=0=^' where id='1';
```

when i select I get:

```
 select * from table where id='1';
```

result:

```
 lT~:uc9%7 4M?;~=0=^
```

I know this is because \0 is being interpretted as a space. How can i get around this.  I need to get the actual value \0

Comment: Do you mean to store a (single)  `NUL` character, or a `\ ` and `0` characters?

Comment: i need to store \0   exactly as it is.   slashzero

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the value

```
lT~:uc9%7\04M?;~=0=^
```

into your field, you've got to use

```
UPDATE yourtable SET field='lT~:uc9%7\\04M?;~=0=^' where id='1';
```

because the backslash is the escape character of MySQL, see

[String Literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html)

```
Escape Sequence  | Character represented by sequence
----------------------------------------------------
\0               | An ASCII NUL (0x00) character
\\               | A backslash (“\”) character.
```

so `\0` is not interpreted as a space. If you want to use a space in a string, simply use a space.